# UINavigationController calls willMoveToWindow and didMoveToWindow twice on a view, in the case of show animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I want to be able to check when a view, let's call him myView, goes on/off screen.

I was able to do so by checking if willMoveToWindow and didMoveToWindow are called on myView.

My problem started with UINavaigationController with animation:

Lets say we have a two screens: 
Screen A with a button that will result in a Show segue with a back button as the navigation control.

The problem is:
The views of screen A are called twice once clicking on the button:

- The first time viewWillMoveToWindow is called with THE REAL WINDOW.
- Then, in the next cycle, the view is called with a nil window.

In between those two calls, I get an illegal state in which I think the view is about to be presented, although he will be removed soon..

I tried to resolve this by using the _transitionAnimationContext on the navigation controller and see who is the fromViewController. If it is my VC, I will ignore the call, since I am about to be removed.
The problem with this approach is the use of private APIs, which I am trying to avoid.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I will answer my own question :)

After searching and searching, I came across the following UIViewController extension:

```
@interface UIViewController(UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nullable) id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> transitionCoordinator NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

in UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator.h

This property holds the current transition coordinator, from which you can reach the fromViewController, which in this case will indicate the view willMoveToWindow for transition and not for presentation.

Enjoy!